# PhpStorm & PHPUnit 6 : PhpStorm always creates PHPUnit templates for < 5

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, config

I am trying to run some PHPUnit 6 tests in PhpStorm. These are my configurations.

Copies the .phar file to my machine following instructions in [here](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html). 
And now, I can verify my version, 
[image]

I have configured PHP7 in PhpStorm
[image]

But, I cannot seem to create PHPUnit 6 tests in the IDE.
When I try to autocreate templates (new->phpunit), the templates have the pre PHPUnit 6 format
[image]

I tried to create the tests manually as well, but PhpStorm cannot find the PHPUnit 6 classes.
I have PhpStorm pointing to the phpunit phar file.
[image]

I am in a fix here.

PhpStorm also complains the class `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` can't be found. So I can't work with the new PHPUnit or the old one.

Am I missing something?

Comment: *"Am I missing something?"* Yes -- the fact that PhpStorm does not support PHPUnit 6 yet. Support should be added for 2017.1 . Template can be altered at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File & Code Templates`

Comment: *"So I can't work with the new PHPUnit or the old one."* PhpStorm still works fine with PHPUnit 5 (using it on daily basis). Get phpunit.phar for PHPUnit 5 (download form PHPUnit website) .. or install it using Composer.

Comment: The main thing that has changed in PHPUnit 6 (simply speaking; in regards to how this integration works in PhpStorm) is that now all PHPUnit classes are namespaced (`PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` vs `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`) and PHPUnit support in PhpStorm is relying on presence of `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class (e.g. to recognize such file as a test case etc).

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34957 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: @LazyOne I get the point and I was able to work with PHPUnit 5 in PhpStorm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPUnit 6 support is currently available in the PhpStorm 2017.1 EAP,l which you can run alongside your regular installation.

[Article with more details](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/02/phpstorm-2017-1-eap-171-3019/)

[Download](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program)